# netgear N300 USB mini adapter WNA3100M is unable to connect to wifi on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: wireless, drivers, usb, realtek, netgear

I recently installed ubuntu 15.04 on my desktop.. MY netgear WNA3100M USB wifi adapter cannot connect to tp-link router wifi network. I can see the available network though.and to my horror i can connect to mobile hotspot created on my smartphone.but cannot connect to the wifi router.the same adapter is working on the same machine on windows 8.1 with same router. any help will be appreciated.

```
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 0846:9021 NetGear, Inc.
```

---

```
ayan@joker:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d8:cb:8a:31:54:db  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:6292 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6292 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:649995 (649.9 KB)  TX bytes:649995 (649.9 KB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:cd:fb:30  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6c:b0:ce:6b:0d:cd  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:896 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1376 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:528495 (528.4 KB)  TX bytes:206970 (206.9 KB)
```

---

```
T:  Bus=07 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0846 ProdID=9021 Rev=02.00
S:  Manufacturer=Realtek
S:  Product=NETGEAR WNA3100M
S:  SerialNumber=00e04c000001
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 4 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=rtl8192cu
```

Comment: Try to deactivate 802.11n on your router and give me a ping with @A.B.

Comment: i dont know much about ubuntu..can u tell me how to do that? and please notice that i have finally got it to work with my mobile hotspot. but the cannot connect to the router.. i dont know how it is possible

Comment: Ok, add the output of the command `ifconfig`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: if i copy the output from the terminal and paste it here it says too long by 227 characters.. i have never asked  a question before @A.B.

Comment: if i copy the output from the terminal and paste it here it says too long by 227 characters.. i have never asked  a question before @pilot6

Comment: Read my comment again, please. Do not post it HERE [edit] your post.

Comment: ok done @Pilot6

Comment: Then add output of `usb-devices` but don't post everything, just the section with `Vendor=0846 ProdID=9021`.

Comment: i found this @Pilot6

Comment: So try the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here we go. It is Realtek rtl8192cu. And it is supported (PID & VID)

You can install the working driver this way

```
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8192cu.git
cd rtl8192cu
make
sudo make install
```

**Note** You will need to re-install after each kernel upgrade, unless it is installed with dkms.

Comment: something went wrong.. after restarting,my pc is not responding whenever i plug in the adapter - @Pilot6

Comment: Please add output of `modprobe -c | grep -i 0846 | grep -i 9021`

Comment: And did it install correctly? No errors?

Comment: And `modinfo rtl8192cu`

Comment: the installation was successful. no error.. a borrowed tp-link adapter was working previously.. now its not working anymore.. how can i undo the changes? modprobe -c .... is not returning anything modinfo rtl8192cu is producing an error.. ill post the details tomorrow. its 3 am in the morning @Pilot6

Comment: You can undo by `cd rtlwifi_new; sudo make uninstall`

Comment: actually the whole usb system has gone down.. flash drives are not being detected. but they are listed in the lsusb result @Pilot6

Comment: That is very weird. Only wireless driver has been replaced. Maybe there is a wrong "VID & PID" in that new driver that matches one of your devices. You can just `sudo modprobe rtl8192cu` to stop it. Then compare codes in your lsusb with codes in `rtlwifi_new/rtl8192.cu/sw.c`. Does anything match except your wireless adapter?

Comment: after uninstalling the wireless drivers the usb system came back online..flsh drives are working again. that borrowed tp-link wifi usb adapter is also working.. AGAIN the strange part is that the netgear adapter is detecting the networks. it can even connect to the mobile hotspot but cannot connect to the wifi router.. . is there anything wrong with my router. But then the tplink adapter is working fine with this router.. - @Pilot6

Comment: I do not think anything wrong is with you router, but check what encryption is set there. Check it is AES.

Comment: Thank you pilot @Pilot6. without i would crash and burn!! the last part worked..

Comment: Which one worked? Another driver or AES?

Comment: another driver..router settings were fine -@pilot6

Comment: did u change the answer?? @pilot6?

Comment: Yes I did. I left the working solution. Is it correct or not?