# WiFi through USB Netgear WNA3100M is very slow

Tags: networking, wireless, usb

I hope you have the time and patience to help a Linux novice.

Since wiring up my home office is not practically achievable, I'm trying to use Wi-Fi. My Netgear WNA3100M seems to work, I have connection, but the browser is very slow. It performs very poorly and intermittently in the browser: some times no response at all, a few minutes later pretty good. I should have a 20 Mb connection, but the most I get from speedtests is about 3. While a Windows laptop with built-in Wi-Fi next to my Linux desktop performs at around 20.

I've done some research on the forum and this solution seemed to work: [netgear N300 USB mini adapter WNA3100M is unable to connect to wifi on ubuntu 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/630657/netgear-n300-usb-mini-adapter-wna3100m-is-unable-to-connect-to-wifi-on-ubuntu-15). But after a couple of reboots the problem has returned.

I must add that I've used a PCI-E Wi-Fi adapter (Asus N53) until about a month ago. I couldn't get that card working right on KXStudio and it had been a labour-intensive process just to keep it working on Ubuntu. Might be some drivers or other residue is messing up the Wi-Fi?

I'm currently using Ubuntu and KXStudio.

Thanks in advance for helping me out.

Some outputs that might help:

**lsusb:**

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0846:9021 NetGear, Inc.
```

**usb-devices:**

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=06 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0846 ProdID=9021 Rev=02.00
S:  Manufacturer=Realtek
S:  Product=NETGEAR WNA3100M
S:  SerialNumber=00e04c000001
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 4 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=rtl8192cu
```

**nm-tool:**

```
Device: wlan0  [VGV7519ECD1BE] -----------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            rtl8192cu
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        A4:2B:8C:6D:C9:55
```

**ifconfig:**

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a4:2b:8c:6d:c9:55  
          inet addr:192.168.2.18  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a62b:8cff:fe6d:c955/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1530 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1596 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:641973 (641.9 KB)  TX bytes:262283 (262.2 KB)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you installed that driver without dkms. After a kernel upgrade the driver did not build.

You can install it from ppa with dkms

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8192cu-dkms
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply @Pilot6, your solution has seriously improved the internet connection. Also useful to learn about dkms, did some reading on the subject. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The solution didn't completely work, I'm afraid. After booting up, the WiFi is connected but there is no connectivity (e.g. ping google.com results in an unkown host error). When replugging the USB dongle, the internet connection improves but is still unreliable (ping results in 0-40% packet loss). Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no better driver as far as I know.

Comment: Alright, suppose I can manage with the performance being as it is. Will wait couple of days if anybody comes up with a brilliant plan. Otherwise I will mark your solution as the working answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Final status for me, after one week: internet still doesn't work as consistent as it should. The solution proposed by Pilot6 did however improve the WiFi performance, for which I am glad. Should be a proper solution for others with a similar problem, so I've marked this as 'answered'.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. Here are my details:

- **OS:** Ubuntu 16.04
- **Kernel:** 4.8.15
- **Device causing issue:** Netgear WNA3100M
- **Issue:** Slow internet speed, no DNS resolution, unreliable connection
- **Status after issue solved:** Full internet speed, reliable connection, no issue with DNS resolution

WNA3100M uses [rtl8192](http://www.realtek.com.tw/products/productsView.aspx?Langid=1&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=277) Wi-Fi chip. Issue is seeming to occur because generic Ubuntu driver for rtl8192cu chip is not fully able to handle WNA3100M.

How to solve issue:

**Step 1:**

Install custom driver for WNA3100M. This will replace generic Ubuntu driver for rtl8192cu chip with a custom driver named 8192cu.

To do this, go to this link and follow all steps in Installation section:

https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes

RESTART SYSTEM.

To check whether installation was successful or not, you can run **dkms status** in terminal. The output should say *installed* for driver 8192cu. Here is my output:

```
nirmal@datainsights:~$ dkms status
8192cu, 1.10, 4.8.15-040815-generic, x86_64: installed
```

**Step 2:**

Make sure driver installed in step 1 loads. Your **lsmod** output should show **8192cu**. Like this:

```
nirmal@datainsights:~$ lsmod | grep 8192cu
8192cu                532480  0
```

At the same time, rtl8192cu (generic Ubuntu driver) should not load, so running following command should give nothing back:

```
nirmal@datainsights:~$ lsmod | grep rtl8192cu
```

Read further if your driver is not loading.

If your driver 8192cu is not loading and you have disabled rtl8192cu, your WNA3100M will not be detected and your Wi-Fi will be disabled.

Try loading the driver with **modprobe 8192cu**. Is it returning error? If so, you must solve it and make sure that driver loads.

In my case, driver was not loading because of secure boot option in UEFI BIOS setting. I disabled secure boot option in BIOS menu and driver loaded automatically.

Ways to disabling secure boot in UEFI:

1. Disable secure boot option from UEFI BIOS menu (pressing F2 or DEL when computer starts, going to advanced mode etc. Google with your motherboard's model to find out exact steps)
2. Using mokutil ubuntu package (I have not tried this option)

In a nutshell, you have to install custom driver and make sure it loads.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)